# Android: setImageBitmap vs setImageURI during listview scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with unknown number of custom items, and during scrolling - inside getView) I check if the related image to aConvertView is exist locally and set it to the listview item (aConvertView):

```
    // out of getView(...)

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    BitmapFactory.Options mOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    mOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;


    // Inside getView(...)

    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), picture_file_name);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        **// Which one has less impact on the UI thread?**

        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), mOptions);
        aImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

        // OR

        aImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
```

Of course I have the known problem of scrolling latency, and I want to know the best approach / method to set the ImageView of the item during scrolling.

**Is setImageBitmap has less impact on UI thread than setImageURI?** or both work on the UI and causes the latency.

**Is using new File , File.exists() has an impact on the UI thread?**

Needless to say that I use a holder for my listview items, and used the following params for my listview:

```
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both run on the UI thread. I would say the first one is probably a tiny bit faster than the second one. The second one really depends where the Uri resource comes from (e.g. the uri could point to a remote file not even stored on the phone).

I think the question here is wether or not you should load a bitmap on the UI thread, and the answer is no, especially in a listview. Google published a great tutorial on developers.android.com about loading bitmaps off the UI thread: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Thank you Quanturium for this example, but additional to loading local bitmaps using AsyncTask (which worked perfectly for me), how do you suggest to check if file exist via AsyncTask? knowing that I'm using another AsyncTask too to download the image if it's not exist locally? can I start an AsyncTask (which downloads the image) from AsyncTask (which checks if file exists locally and load it)?

Comment: Yes you can do exactly that.

Comment: `I would say the first one is probably a tiny bit faster than the second one. ` 
It is much faster than second one.

Answer (score 1):

You have latency issues because you are doing file IO on UI thread, mainly `decodeFile` is a problem here, where you actually access file data on the disc (although there is no reason to call `File.exists()` from UI thread either).

Quanturium's answer is correct

Example there explains how to load a bitmap in the background and use `WeakReference` to `ImageView` to assign the bitmap as a background drawable. Keep in mind that all your file IO work should be inside `doInBackground`, `onPostExecute` actually happens on UI thread.

EDIT: How to use File.Exists () in AsyncTask

```
// Decode image in background. 
    @Override 
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), picture_file_name);
        if(file.exists())
        { 
           return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), mOptions);
        }
        else
        {
           return null;
        }
   }
```

NOTE: I don't have access to my dev machine so I'm not sure if this will build.

To answer your question regarding launching one AsyncTask from another - I've never done it, I guess it's possible. In my case, I put all my flow into a single `doInBackground`:

1. First download the data (I'm guessing you're using some REST call to do this).
2. From your response grab the content
3. If file exists, overwrite
4. If file doesn't exist, create

To me, the most important thing is to run both REST call and file IO in the background thread - I don't care if it's a single task or two.

Comment: Thank you Kibler88 for your help and additional explanation, I added a comment with a questions under Quanturium response, and you are very welcome to pitch it :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem before. i was trying to load 6 local large images(using `Uri`) in a `ListView`. There are 2 things you probably have to do in order to make your app run smoothly.

1. Do not load image on the main thread. Here is a android document that how to load image on separate thread:[link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#concurrency).There are many libraries already implement this for you. If you are loading image from internet, server, etc. i would recommend [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

2.Scale the image size to make the image fit `ImageView` better. Here is a android document of how scale the image size. [link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

After all here is my `AsyncTask` class that load image on a new thread and scale the image based on imageview:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private Uri data = null;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        data = params[0];
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.toString(),options);
        options.inSampleSize= calculateInSampleSize(options,300,300);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.toString(),options);

    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

300*300 is my image view size